# A Meeting In/On His Schedule

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

Suppose we are talking about someone's schedule of things to do

> 1. There is a management meeting ***in*** his schedule.
> 2. There is a management meeting ***on*** his schedule.

Should it be "*in*" or "*on*" when talking about what is in someone's schedule?

Comment: See this: http://www.adamsdrafting.com/schedule-in-or-on/ However, the expression "on schedule" means "not early or late".

Comment: @Yulia, I don't know if I'd say that that link applies exactly as I think it's talking about schedules as in [tabular/classified forms](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schedule) (Definition Four), not as in timetables as the OP is referring to here. In the meantime, I have upvoted your comment as I do agree that the OP should be careful in distinguishing between "on the schedule" and "on schedule."

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would go with "**in**" for your example sentence because it's talking about a person's specific schedule. For example,

> There's been a change in [his] schedule.
>
> [PhraseMix](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/a-change-in-the-schedule) website

However, if you want to talk about schedules in general, you could use "**on**":

> What's *on the* schedule for today?
>
> [Faith for the Journey: A Spiritual Memoir](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=RxhjCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%22what%27s%20on%20the%20schedule%20for%20today%22&source=bl&ots=ThDi7FNTFy&sig=eoL5F9M_pHzXmbw-FUPgI_5J67k&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI1-zvnMTTAhVHS7wKHUCMBV4Q6AEIZjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22what%27s%20on%20the%20schedule%20for%20today%22&f=false), Carol Blair

or

> I want to be *on the* speaking schedule.
>
> [Speak in Levels](http://www.speakinlevels.com/i-want-to-be-on-the-schedule/) website

So, as usual, context matters.

---

In the meantime, a couple of things to be careful of:

1. I would take @Yulia's comment into consideration, that is, be careful not to say, "on schedule" when you mean "on the schedule."

   - "[On schedule](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=on%20schedule%20definition&oq=on%20schedule%20definition&gs_l=serp.3..0i30k1.2448.4249.0.4400.11.4.0.7.7.0.105.250.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.10.362...0j0i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i8i30i19k1.fab8zibYpNk)" means "on time" whereas "on the schedule" means "on the timetable."
2. When talking about one of the other definitions of schedules, such as a table or a form ("[Schedule](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schedule)," Definition Four, Dictionary.com), I would almost always use "in the schedule."

   - But again, as [the link in @Yulia's comment](http://www.adamsdrafting.com/schedule-in-or-on/) points out, "So I recommend that you use *in* rather than *on*. But nothing is riding on this distinction."

Comment: I don’t see how the fact that it’s talking about one person’s schedule in particular affects the preposition. Either one would be fine.

Comment: To the OP: taking into account J.R.'s comment, I'd have to say, "There is a management meeting on his schedule" (number two of your original examples) doesn't sound idiomatic to me, which is why I suggest you stick with "in" when the schedule is a particular person's. On the other hand, I would also agree with J.R. that if your original examples had been: "There is a management meeting __ *the* schedule," I would be OK with both "in" or "on."

Comment: "There is a management meeting on his schedule" sounds both normal and idiomatic to me.